# Disabling authentication in “OAUTH2” enabled boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

How to disable authentication in “OAUTH2” enabled spring-boot application?
This is often required for testing or during build phase.

Answer (score 3):

This is a valid scenario when we want to do the testing/build and we don’t have OAuth2 token available on the fly.
Below are the steps to be followed:

1. Create a YAML file without OAuth2 configuration (i.e. `application-{profile_name}.yml`) and add below properties in it:

   ```
   Security.ignored = /** 
   security.basic.enable=false
   ```
2. Add a class which is bypassing HTTP/S requests authorization.  Note: This class should have same profile name (i.e. `{profile_name}`).

   ```java
   @Profile({"profile_name"})
   public class DisableOAuth2Config {

       @Bean
       public ResourceServerConfigurer resourceServerConfigurer() {
           return new ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter() {
               @Override
               public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                   http
                       .authorizeRequests()
                           .antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
               }
           };
       }
   }
   ```
3. Provide `Profile` in `SecurityConfiguration` class where we still want to have security. `@Profile({"local","dev","aws"})`, This will differentiate profiles for both enabled/disabled security.
4. Note: Please check annotations `@EnableResourceServe`, `@EnableWebSecurity` and `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)`. They should be available only in `SecurityConfiguration` class. Not multiple places and not in `SpringBoot` class.